# AutoFill issue on iOS for getting phone number

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Autofill suggestion fails to populate textfield when tapped on keyboard. Here's what I'm making in my code:

```
textField.keyboardType = .phonePad
textField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
```

But when function

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

is called it just returns empty replacementString string.

Device ios version 14.7

EDIT:
I found out that if i dont specify/delegate

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

function everything works perfectly. Still confused why.

Comment: Have found any fix for this. I also need to add validation while typing. Please let me know if you found solution.

Answer (score 0):

try after set content  type to otp

```
textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Comment: But changing textContentType will lead to autofill suggestion changing from phone number to message one time code which is not my intention for this particular textfield cause I want user being able fastforward default textfields.

Comment: apple not provide OTP with any other form

Answer (score 0):

Anybody still wondering how to implement validation while entering in UITextField and also allow auto suggestion.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

will not work.

What I did and worked for me was

added target on UITextField

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and implement logic in

```
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //.... logic for validation
}
```